# Need to put a text view indicating the button something similar like cart count

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

This is a live code unable to change the layout types, in this you will see four relative layouts inside linear layout where I need to put count of each segment indicating something like add to cart or cart count.

Here is the XML code of the layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bid" />

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View and start bidding"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Button">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/num"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/a_a1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/num"
                    android:text="Number Plate"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel2"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Button">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/phone"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/a_a2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
                    android:text="Phone Numbers"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel4"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Button">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/auto"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/a_a3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/auto"
                    android:text="AutoMobile"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel42"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Button">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/esrate"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/a_a4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/esrate"
                    android:text="Real Estate"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can set Badge Counter like this
http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/adding-badge-item-count-to-android-button.html